# Excel UDF to specify Table Row and Col by Name

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

Given an Excel table such as that in the image below

[image]

I know how to use VLOOKUP and MATCH to access data elements using "symbolic names" for rows and columns - a column name for the latter, a search key for the former.

At least, I know how to do this in an Excel formula.

```
=VLOOKUP("RowA",Table2,MATCH("ColA",Table2[#Headers],0))
```

But this is pretty verbose.

I would like to abbreviate it as a UDF (User Defined Function)

(TRC standing for "Table Row Column")

skeleton looking like

```
Function TRC(tbl As Range, rowName, colName) 
  'in Table tbl, 
  'looks up value whose row key is rowVal, 
  'and whose column heading is colVal
  ...
End Function
```

that might  be called as follows, for a semi-realistic example, where columns are particular CPU models, and rows are uarch parameters.

```
Cache_Size_in_Bytes = TRC(Cache_Param_Table,"Line_Size","Pentium4")
```

or placed in a formukla in a cell like

```
= TRC(Cache_Param_Table,"Line_Size","Pentium4")
```

Unfortunately, I have not managed to get anything working.

Help?

Comment: you mean whose value is rowName  and colName?

Comment: "whose value is rowName and colName?" - yes.  More precisely, I mean the cell of the table (passed as parameter tbl),. whose column is the column that has the value of the string colName in the #Headers row, and whose row has the value of the parameter rowName as the value of - in this example - the column whose header is "RowKey".  // An extended version might pass in the column header name to be used for the RowKey.

Comment: Sounds like you could use index on tbl with match and match for rowName and colName. That would return the row and column you need and thus the value.

Comment: @QHarr - yeah, I have used both VLOOKUP/MATCH and INDEX-MATCH in my formulae.  I just haven't been able to transform those formulae into VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this? I would advise using a more descriptive function name.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim table As ListObject
    Set table = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("table2")
    Debug.Print TRC(table.Range, "RowA", "ColB")
End Sub


Public Function TRC(ByVal table As Range, ByVal rowName As String, ByVal colName As String) As Variant
    TRC = Application.Index(table, Application.Match(rowName, table.Columns(1), 0), Application.Match(colName, table.Rows(1), 0))
End Function
```

---

You could customize function with error handling/alternative return values e.g.

```
Public Function TRC(ByVal table As Range, ByVal rowName As String, ByVal colName As String) As Variant
    Dim ret As Variant
    ret = Application.Index(table, Application.Match(rowName, table.Columns(1), 0), Application.Match(colName, table.Rows(1), 0))
    If Not IsError(ret) Then
        TRC = ret
    Else
        TRC = "Not found"
    End If
End Function
```

---

In sheet usage:

```
=TRC(Table2[#All],"RowA","ColB")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Function TRC(tbl As Range, rowName, colName)

  aRow = -1
  aColumn = -1
  For j = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
    If tbl.Cells(j, 1) = rowName Then aRow = j
  Next j
  For k = 1 To tbl.Columns.Count
    If tbl.Cells(1, k) = colName Then aColumn = k
  Next k
  If (aRow = -1) Or (aColumn = -1) Then
    TRC = "Error"
  Else
    TRC = tbl.Cells(aRow, aColumn)
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Ugh!  Is there no way to call INDEX or VLOOKUP directly from the UDF, so that the code corresponds to the formula?   //  Anyway, not complaining, I can understand what you are doing, although I haven't tested it yet.  Thanks. This may become accepted answer, but still!!!